# Delphi 2010 with earlier compiler

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Is it possible to use de Delphi 7 compiler inside Delphi 2010 IDE?

We want to migrate at some point in the future to 2010 from D7 but for now we are stuck because of many unUnicode sources and components. But we want to enjoy the many many Delphi 2010 IDE features everybody are talking about.

Is it possible? How it's done?
What are problems we could face?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check  The ***[IDE Compiler Plugin v.1.0](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=160)*** wich makes it possible to compile a Delphi project from the IDE with an older or newer Delphi compiler version. It can be used to compile a Delphi 2007 project with the Delphi 2009 compiler to get an UNICODE version of the executables or the other way round. For component developers this plugin makes it possible to compile their components for different Delphi versions within one IDE. And Delphi 2007 users can “test-compile” their projects against the Unicode Delphi 2009 compiler.

> Features:
>
> - Can plug in every command line compiler
> - Add/Remove Delphi compiler options
> - Redirect search paths
> - Modify the compiler’s command line on the fly
> - Predefined 2009 compiler configuration for Delphi 2007
> - Predefined 2007 compiler configuration for Delphi 2009
>
> Requirements:
>
> - Delphi 2007 and 2009 must be installed
>
> Limitations:
>
> - It is not possible to debug the code that was compiled by the plugged in
>     compiler.

That is the only tool I know, unfortunately it is not compatible with Delphi 2010.

Bye.

Comment: really unfortunate it doesn't work with 2010, I won't use D2009 if 2010 is available

Answer (score 1):

You could use the new build events to kick off a command line compile with the D7 after the D2010 compile finishes.